# Handling errors from 3rd party API

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm working with a 3rd party `xmlrpc API`. Errors can be returned as a string or an array. I need to handle and format these errors to make user friendly. The API doesn't use fault codes/strings.

I'm currently using a `switch-case` but looking to improve.

Existing code:

```
switch ($result) { // removed some blocks for sake of post
        case 'Error:malformed_mac':
              $result = $_POST['params'][0] . " is malformed. Please check you have entered it correctly.";
            break;
        case 'Error:no_such_mac':
            $result = "Sorry, " . $_POST['params'][0] . " hasn't been registered.";
            break;
 }
```

Is there anyway I could declare an array of all the possible errors as keys and the custom message as the value:

> $errors = ['Error:no_such_mac' => 'custom error message1',
>   'Error:malformed_mac' => 'custom error message2'];

Then if the key exists in the response print out the corresponding value? Or is there another way I could achieve this?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with the following:

> $errors = [
>            "Error:no_such_mac" => "Mac address doesn't exist",
>            "Error:malformed_mac" => "Mac address is malformed"
>       ];

```
$word = "Error:no_such_mac";
echo strtr($word,$arr);
```

Output:

> Mac address doesn't exist.

If there is a better solution please post and I will mark as accepted answer.